# Draw a stratified random sampling with multiple strata

Tags: r, random, sample

I have a population grouped based on four strata: gender, age, education and residence. Imagine for example this randomly composed data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(index <- c(1:100),
                 gender <- sample(c("male", "female"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 age <- sample(c("young", "middle-aged", "old"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 education <- sample(c("low", "middle", "high"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 residence <- sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)
colnames(df) <- c("index", "gender", "age", "education", "residence")
```

I want to draw a random sample of 30 people from this population, stratified based on the four strata such that it comprises: for gender, 15 women and 15 men; for age, 8 young, 10 middle-aged and 12 old; for education, 11 low, 8 middle and 11 high; and for residence, 11 from region A, 9 from region B, 4 from region C, 4 from region D and 2 from region E.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Do you want to draw with or without replacement?

Comment: Without replacement, i.e. every observation can only be drawn once.